# How to use the MySQL server running on my local machine inside the docker container for a DropWizard application?

Tags: java, mysql, docker, dropwizard

I'm new to Docker and am currently struggling with containerizing my dropwizard application. Each time I build the container, run it, and check the logs, I get the MySQL connection failure error which makes sense as the container runs on a virtual machine and for it the localhost URL means nothing. I was wondering what can I do to make my MySQL accessible inside my docker container. Thanks.  This is how my config.yml file looks like rn.

````
  driverClass: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  # the username
  user: root

  # the password
  password:

  # the JDBC URL
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/locations?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC

  # any properties specific to your JDBC driver:
  properties:
    charSet: UTF-8

  # the maximum amount of time to wait on an empty pool before throwing an exception
  maxWaitForConnection: 1s

  # the SQL query to run when validating a connection's liveness
  validationQuery: "/* MyService Health Check */ SELECT 1"

  # the timeout before a connection validation queries fail
  validationQueryTimeout: 3s

  # the minimum number of connections to keep open
  minSize: 8

  # the maximum number of connections to keep open
  maxSize: 32

  # whether or not idle connections should be validated
  checkConnectionWhileIdle: false

  # the amount of time to sleep between runs of the idle connection validation, abandoned cleaner and idle pool resizing
  evictionInterval: 10s

  # the minimum amount of time an connection must sit idle in the pool before it is eligible for eviction
  minIdleTime: 1 minute

  # Logging settings.
#logging:
#  level: INFO
#  loggers:
#    io.dropwizard: DEBUG
#    org.eclipse.jetty.servlets: DEBUG
#    org.hibernate.SQL: ALL
#    com.udemy.LocationsApplication:
#      level: ALL,
#      additive: false
#      appenders:
#        - type: conso
#          logFormat: "%red(CDR) [%magenta(%date)] [%thread] [%cyan(%logger{0})]: %message%n"
#  appenders:
#    - type: console
#      logFormat: "%highlight(%-5level) [%magenta(%date)] [%thread] [%cyan(%logger{0})]: %message%n" ```
````

Comment: Where is the database running?  (Directly on the host, in a VM, in a container?)  Is Docker in a separate VM, or are you running the Docker daemon directly on a native-Linux host, or using a system like Docker Desktop or Docker Toolbox?  Have you looked at questions like [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a mysql container exposing the port `3306` and your dropwizard container.

You can create a network for them

```
docker network create <network_name>
```

And assign it to the dockers

```
docker run .... --network <network_name>
```

This should make that bot dockers see each other

You can see the networks you have using `docker network ls` if you use `docker-compose` it will generate the networks automatically.

You can also use the `host` network which also makes them able to connect to ports in your machine (the virtual machine if you are running docker in one of those)

Comment: I had already created my dropwizard container. I created a container for MySQL, configured it to allow connections from any host, populated it with necessary tables and data, and then created a network. Then I used "docker network connect" to add both the containers to my network. Now it says "connection refused". Any idea how to proceed? Thanks

Comment: If i'm not wrong you should change `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306` to `jdbc:mysql://<container-name>:3306`

Comment: Yep it worked! I'm so dumb, I was modifying the local config.yml file instead of the one inside the docker folder.